# Cannot select rows in dataframe made from .xlsx file

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

This is the first question here. I have recently decided to use python to work with my excel files and doing some plots.
I have created the dataframe as follows:

```
df_2d6=pd.read_excel(r'file_location\file_name.xlsx')
print(df_2d6)
```

From which I get this:

```
Unnamed: 0 Trace/Retrace  Write (V)  Read (V)  ...  cQuad (mV)  A0*sign(InP) (mV)  A0/Q (mV)  A0*sign(InP)/Q (mV)

0             2         trace   0.204082      -1.0  ...   -4.574200          -7.548735   0.087311            -0.087311
1             4         trace   0.612245      -1.0  ...   -0.141285                NaN        NaN                  NaN
2             6         trace   1.020410      -1.0  ...    6.170378          18.765411   0.195054             0.195054
3             8         trace   1.428570      -1.0  ...   11.385813          28.527952   0.273230             0.273230
4            10         trace   1.836730      -1.0  ...   11.445871          26.246212   0.257342             0.257342
..          ...           ...        ...       ...  ...         ...                ...        ...                  ...
877        1756         trace  -1.836730       1.0  ...   42.489041          57.953414   0.518969             0.518969
878        1758         trace  -1.428570       1.0  ...   43.603410          56.802126   0.501349             0.501349
879        1760         trace  -1.020410       1.0  ...   41.080861          55.435172   0.494170             0.494170
880        1762         trace  -0.612245       1.0  ...   39.813781          53.232177   0.465081             0.465081
881        1764         trace  -0.204082       1.0  ...   38.638920          51.728388   0.457760             0.457760
```

I wanted to select the values of column "Read (V)" equal to "-0.5" to plot them. But when subsetting the dataframe these are not selected resulting in an empty dataframe:

```
>>> surfpot=df_2d6[df_2d6["Read (V)"]=="0.5"]
>>> print(surfpot)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Unnamed: 0, Trace/Retrace, Write (V), Read (V), A0 (mV), f0 (kHz), Q, R^2, ph0 (o), InP (mV), Quad (mV), cInP (mV), cQuad (mV), A0*sign(InP) (mV), A0/Q (mV), A0*sign(InP)/Q (mV)]
Index: []
```

Do you have any idea about this?

I also had to change the name of the subsetting from "2d6_surfpot" to just "surfpot" because it would give me a syntax error, I could not figure out why either

Thank you and congratulations for this nice community :)

I have tried to select only the column from the original dataframe and it worked fine:

```
df_2d6["Read (V)"]
0     -1.0
1     -1.0
2     -1.0
3     -1.0
4     -1.0
      ...
877    1.0
878    1.0
879    1.0
880    1.0
881    1.0
```

the issue seem to be when subsetting the dataframe:

```
subdf_2d6=df_2d6[df_2d6["Read (V)"]]; print(subdf_2d6)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "L:\Anaconda\3.9\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3511, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns._get_indexer_strict(key, "columns")[1]
  File "L:\Anaconda\3.9\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 5782, in _get_indexer_strict
    self._raise_if_missing(keyarr, indexer, axis_name)
  File "L:\Anaconda\3.9\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 5842, in _raise_if_missing
    raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
KeyError: "None of [Float64Index([-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,\n              ...\n               1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0],\n             dtype='float64', length=882)] are in the [columns]"
```

No idea now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the datatype of the column is `float` but you are checking for string `"0.5"`.

So you should do ...

```
surfpot = df_2d6[df_2d6["Read (V)"] == 0.5]  # removed the double quotes
```

... instead of ...

```
surfpot = df_2d6[df_2d6["Read (V)"] == "0.5"]
```

Comment: Hi Ashyam, thank you for spotting that. I have tried and it work, but I am still not sure why it did not when I selected the whole column as per last example